# Have form load with previously chosen values on a different page, but load blank if this page is opened on its own

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a reservation booking site and have 2 pages. My index.html page has 2 ways to access the bookroom.html page.

The first way is a regular link in the heading. When accessed this way, I want the bookroom.html page to load with a default heading reading "Room Details" and the form on it to load blank with no values chosen (where my current issue is).

The second way is a "Check Availability" section where the user can pre-select a destination, check-in, and check-out date. This section has a button which opens the bookroom.html page, and by using sessionStorage().getItem/setItem I am passing the details chosen here to the new form on the new bookroom.html page with the remaining form sections blank to be filled out.

My problem is that now that I have created the JS to pass the values to the bookroom.html page, I can no longer open the bookroom.html page on its own with the default heading and the destination showing its first value "placeholder". I am thinking this is because of the window.addEventListener being 'load' however I am stuck on if this is the issue and how to get around it.

index.html

```
<form action="./PreLogin/bookroom/bookroom.html" method="POST" class="form" id="form">
            <!-- Destination Choice -->
            <div class="destination-div">
              <label for="" class="input-label"></label>
              <select class="destination-choice" id="destination" name="destination">
                <option value="Choose Destination" disabled selected hidden>Choose Destination</option>
                <option value="New York">New York</option>
                <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
                <option value="California">California</option>
                <option value="Texas">Texas</option>
              </select> 
            </div>
            <!-- Check In Choice -->
            <div class="check-in-date-div">
              <label for="" class="input-label">Check In</label>
              <input type="date" class="input" id="checkin-date" name="checkin-date" min="2022-09-01">
            </div>
            <!-- Check Out Choice -->
            <div class="check-out-date-div">
              <label for="" class="input-label">Check Out</label>
              <input type="date" class="input" id="checkout-date" name="checkout-date" min="2022-09-01">
            </div>
            <!-- Check Button -->
            <div class="check-button-div">
              <button type="submit" form="form" class="check-availability-button" onclick="checkAvailability()" >Check Availability</button>
            </div>
</form>
```

index.js

```
function checkAvailability () {

    const destination = document.getElementById('destination').value;
    const checkin = document.getElementById('checkin-date').value;
    const checkout = document.getElementById('checkout-date').value;

    sessionStorage.setItem("DESTINATION", destination);
    sessionStorage.setItem("CHECKIN-DATE", checkin);
    sessionStorage.setItem("CHECKOUT-DATE", checkout);

    return;
}
```

bookroom.html

```
<!-- SUB HEADER (CHECK AVAILABILITY) START -->
      <div class="sub-header-div">
        <div class="check-availability-div">
          <h1 class="sub-header-text" id="result-destination-header"> Room Details </h1>
        </div>
      </div>
<!-- SUB HEADER END -->

<form action="">
        <h1>
            Result Page
        </h1>
        <select class="destination-choice" id="result-destination">
            <option value="Choose Destination" disabled selected hidden>Choose Destination</option>
            <option value="New York">New York</option>
            <option value="Florida">Florida</option>
            <option value="California">California</option>
            <option value="Texas">Texas</option> 
        </select> 
        <!-- <input type="text" id="result-name" /> -->
        <input type="date" id="result-checkin" />
        <input type="date" id="result-checkout" />
        <input type="text" id="result-name" placeholder="Enter Your Name..." />
</form>
```

bookroom.js

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    
    const destination = sessionStorage.getItem('DESTINATION');
    const checkin = sessionStorage.getItem('CHECKIN-DATE');
    const checkout = sessionStorage.getItem('CHECKOUT-DATE');
    
    document.getElementById('result-destination-header').innerHTML = destination;
    document.getElementById('result-destination').value = destination;
    document.getElementById('result-checkin').value = checkin;
    document.getElementById('result-checkout').value = checkout;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To check whether your *bookroom.html* page was accessed through the link in your *index.html* page, or not...

First add a `checkavailability` [URL search/query string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) parameter to the *index.html* form `action` attribute:

```
<form action="book.html?checkavailability" method="POST" class="form" id="form">
```

Then wrap your *bookroom.js* session variable form update code with a check for the existence of that parameter:

```
window.addEventListener('load', () => {

  // GET LOCATION QUERY STRING OBJECT
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);

  // CHECK FOR "checkavailability" QUERY STRING PARAMETER
  if (null !== params.get("checkavailability")) { // yay, found it

    const destination = sessionStorage.getItem('DESTINATION');
    const checkin = sessionStorage.getItem('CHECKIN-DATE');
    const checkout = sessionStorage.getItem('CHECKOUT-DATE');

    document.getElementById('result-destination-header').innerHTML = destination;
    document.getElementById('result-destination').value = destination;
    document.getElementById('result-checkin').value = checkin;
    document.getElementById('result-checkout').value = checkout;
  }

});
```

...using [`URLSearchParams()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams), [`location.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search) and the *URLSearchParams* method [`get()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get).

Of course, the name `checkavailability` is simply a (user-friendly) suggestion—you can use any (variable name compliant) name you like.

Comment: It seems that when I do this method the bookroom.html page is not getting the values from the index.html page passed anymore. The bookroom.html page is however loading with its default values. I did update the form's action="...html?checkavailability" to match my correct file path.

Comment: Actually, I was mistaken! Your answer solved my issue! Thank you so much for the help and I am going to spend more time researching URLSearchParams() now. I needed to add the " window.addEventListener('load', () => { " inside of the if statement just as my initial bookroom.js was written. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out—I forgot to include the window load event listener in my answer. I actually have the `URLSearchParams` and `if` statement wrapped in the load hander. But it works either way.